# How to verify non-negativity of a density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, density-operator

A density matrix, $\rho$ must be Hermitian, normalized ($Tr[\rho]=1$) and non negative. Non negativity means that it should have non negative eigenvalues. Given a density matrix, first two conditions are straightforward to check. But, how to verify the non negativity of a density matrix without explicitly calculating the eigenvalues? The eigenvalue calculation can be very difficult for an arbitrary dimensional density matrix.

Comment: I doubt there is any other way than calculating all the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a computer, (and probably also on paper for a matrix with no partiuclar structure), the fastest solution is computing a [Cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_factorization) and seeing if the procedure fails. This in the end is a special case of the criterion in QMechanic's answer, since you are constructing a factorization $\rho = BB^\dagger$. (You may replace it with a LDL^T factorization to avoid the square roots.)

In some cases if the matrix has a special structure it may be easier to compute determinants and check Sylvester's criterion, as suggested by AccidentalFourierTransform.

Answer (score 5):

A [non-negative](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Positive_operator) (aka. [semi-positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element)) operator$^{1}$ $\rho:H\to H$ satisfies by definition
$$ \forall v\in H: \langle v, \rho v \rangle ~\geq~ 0. \tag{1}$$

For a complex Hilbert space, an operator $\rho$ is semi-positive iff 
$$ \exists B: ~~ \rho~=~B^{\dagger} B, \tag{2}$$
and iff
$$\rho \text{ is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis with non-negative eigenvalues.} \tag{3} $$

The characterizations (1) & (2) are often simpler to use than determining the spectrum/eigenvalues (3).

---

$^{1}$We will ignore subtleties with [unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), domains, [selfadjoint extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators), etc., in this answer.

Comment: Would you please give an explicit example illustrating this procedure?

Comment: @Qmechanic Your footnote is not necessary, what you wrote is correct with the only hypothesis (you assumed) that the domain of $\rho$ is the whole Hilbert space.

Comment: @Valter Moretti: I agree.

Comment: Note also: If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then the most easily implemented criterion for positive-definiteness is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).